# What are the necessary js files for semantic-ui dropdown to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I am try to use `semantic-ui` dropdown and `dropdown.js` is included but it is not working properly. It expends but not closed on click.
When I use `semantic-ui.min.js` file (all files bundled) it work fine.

**So which js files are necessary to work it properly.**

Comment: Problem solved just after posting this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding and removing all files one by one I found that these files needed.

```
<script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/transition.js"></script>
```